# PHP grouped up data by their dates and put them in an array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this data from my database, this is for this student

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 18
            [student_id] => 97
            [date] => 2018-08-31
            [type] => Intersexual Dormitory Visit
            [amount] => 0
            [count] => 3
            [remark] => 
            [reg_date] => 2018-09-04 16:50:16
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 17
            [student_id] => 97
            [date] => 2018-09-04
            [type] => Bringing or Drinking alcohol
            [amount] => 0
            [count] => 1
            [remark] => 
            [reg_date] => 2018-09-04 16:48:54
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 16
            [student_id] => 97
            [date] => 2018-09-04
            [type] => Throwing away wastes
            [amount] => 0
            [count] => 1
            [remark] => 
            [reg_date] => 2018-09-04 15:52:09
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 15
            [student_id] => 97
            [date] => 2018-09-04
            [type] => Class Late
            [amount] => 300
            [count] => 1
            [remark] => absent 1 class
            [reg_date] => 2018-09-04 15:46:19
        )

)
```

What I wanted to do is to group them up depends on the `date (Year and Month)`, and when the `amount` is 0, it is counted as a `warning` and when greater than 0 is counted as a `penalty`.

This is my attempt:

```
public function getChart($in_data)
{
    $this->load->model('student_model');

    $student_info = $this->student_model->selectItem($in_data);

    $count_warning = 0;
    $count_penalty = 0;

    $chart = array();
    $items = parent::getItems(array('student_id'=>$student_info->member_id)); //this is for getting the Output

    foreach ($items as $item) {

        $count = array('penalty'=>0, 'warning'=>0);

        if ($item->amount > 0) {
            $count['penalty'] += $item->count;
        } else {
            $count['warning'] += $item->count;
        }

        $chart[date('Y-m', strtotime($item->date))] = $count;
    }

    return $chart;
}
```

But it resulted as this:

```
Array
(
    [2018-08] => Array
        (
            [penalty] => 0
            [warning] => 3
        )

    [2018-09] => Array
        (
            [penalty] => 1
            [warning] => 0
        )

)
```

The thing is he only has 3 warning in august and has 2 warnings and 1 penalty for september, that would be my desired output, how will I make it like that?

Comment: I see 3 warnings in August.  Why would you count 3 in 1 month as 1?

Comment: Yeah my bad I edited it sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go (untested):

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
      //just because I can (use array key for ease of accessing it)
      $key = preg_replace('/-\d{2}$/', '', $item['date']);
      //you can use this instead if you want.
      //$key = date('Y-m', strtotime($item->date));

       //we can join our ifs tougher as the deal with the same elements
       //and this will make the code more efficient
      if(!isset($chart[$key])){
         //add $key as month
         $chart[$key] = array('penalty'=>0, 'warning'=>0, 'month'=>$key);         
      }else if ($item->amount > 0) {
         $chart[$key]['penalty'] += $item->count;
      } else {
         $chart[$key]['warning'] += $item->count;
      }

}

 //may want to put the proper content type
 //this tells the ajax call what it is and will parse it 
 //automatically in most browsers, so you can toss that JSON.parse().
 //CAUTION:do not output data before a header call
 //header('Content-type: application/json'); 

 //array_values removes the date key, its easier to built array with it.
 //then we just output the json
 echo json_encode(array_values($chart));
```

[Regex Test](https://regex101.com/r/CTzVYs/1)

Regex

- `-` match `-` literally
- `\d` match any digit
- `{2}` exactly 2 times
- `$` match end of string.

In short it replaces the 2018-08`-31` part.  Use the date function if you are sure it will always be a valid date.  You can use the regex if it's not or you don't feel like using the date ...

As a side note, I would have tested it had you used `var_export` instead of `print_r` to output the data, because I am to lazy to format it.  One of these days I will write something to convert it for me.

As a second side note I added the header (in comments), if your data is not parsed correctly by the ajax callback then you can use this and it should come out as an object, like it's supposed to.  However, some older browsers may have issues with this, such as IE8 maybe IE9 too etc. Because they don't understand it they may try to download a JSON file.  So it depends on if you plan to support those.

Cheers.

Comment: I works fine but I wanted to use it in json format, I want the output to be like this `{"month":"2018-08","penalty":0,"warning":3},{"month":"2018-09","penalty":1,"warning":2}`

Comment: Show me where it says that in the question.  I'm not psychic after all.  Besides you can do `json_encode($chart)`, simple.

Comment: Im sorry, I customize your code with this `$chart[$key] = array('month'=> date('Y-m', strtotime($item->date)), 'penalty'=>0, 'warning'=>0);` and with `json_encode($chart)` it resulted as this: `{"2018-08":{"month":"2018-08","penalty":0,"warning":3},"2018-09":{"month":"2018-09","penalty":1,"warning":2}}` but only want the output to be like the first comment. Im sorry sir

Comment: there I fixed it.  Use `array_values` to remove the top level key, then encode, and the key in as month.  When I read the question I thought you wanted the array at the bottom, you should have posted the JSON too.   Oh no biggie.